# atheros ar5bmd22 wifi drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, atheros

I have >120mb BB connection, via wifi on windows i get around 90+mb connection.

I have an Asus RT-N66U Dark Night router, like i said on all other devices i have no issue. But using ubuntu 12.10 on my ultrabook i'm lucky if i get +10mb and the connection is very temperamental.

Even simple actions like updating take an age to do via wifi.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this command and put the result?
`sudo lshw -class network`

Also, what computer are you using?

Comment: I just gave in and went back to 12.04 which worked, i'll leave updating until a new LTS is released.